# REST API Not saving products Magento2

Tags: magento2, products, rest-api, repository

Using the REST api of M2 and for some reason I can't save a new product ?

Here's my code

[image]

Here's the error I get.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You do not fill all required product properties, for example, product_type

Comment: Also the 'status' property is missing